# CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter swagger ui lowercase / upper case format problem

Tags: spring-boot, enums, swagger-ui

I need to use my Enum as lowercase in swagger ui, but I need to transfer the Enum data as capital inside the application.

I have updated my Product enum as below, if I add only this class to my application. I list the enum in a combobox and take an error afterwards.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public enum Product {
        CREATEDAT("createdAt"),
        UPDATEDAT("updatedAt"),
        NAME("name");

        private final String value;

        @JsonValue
        public String getValue() {
            return value.toLowerCase();
        }

    }
```

[image]

but when I send the request it tooks an error on String to Enum conversion

```
 "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'Product'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam Product] for value 'updatedAt'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Product.updatedAt"

---
```

Then I add the following case sensitivity conversion classes then it ruins the enum listing and only shows the first item as Uppercase.

and If I manually type lowercase in swagger-ui it works on the service layer.

How could I fix this ?

Thanks.

[image]

---

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
public class CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<String, T> {
    private Class<T> enumClass;
    public CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }
    @Override
    public T convert(String from) {
        return T.valueOf(enumClass, from.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

---

```
import com.example.enums.EnumA;
import com.example.enums.EnumB;
import com.example.enums.FormatEnum;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import java.util.List;
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        List<Class<? extends Enum>> enums = List.of(Product.class);
        enums.forEach(enumClass -> registry.addConverter(String.class, enumClass,
                      new CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter<>(enumClass)));
    }
}
```